# Magento 1.9 Customer Login Not Working In Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, magento, magento-1.9

I have a Magento site version 1.9. The customer login works in Safari, Edge, IE, but does not work in Chrome.

I have tried adding the following to the login files, but have still not had any success.

getFormKey(); ?>" />

The Session Cookie Management cookie lifetime is set to 86400.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: clear your chrome browser cache

Answer (score 1):

After trying both the solutions, if you still face an issue, you need to set cookie domain along with dot at the start of the domain and your login will again start working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Go to : Magento backend -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management

and add Cookie Domain example : .yourdomain.com

and for testing its recommended to clear your browser cookie on which you are testing.